# Bug Open and close a nav

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a little bug, when i click on a link to open children, it close all the item, please see the Gif :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZMjZ.gif)

This is my JS code :

```
$('.menu-item-has-children > a').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
    var EltToToggle = $(this).next('.sub-menu');
   $(".sub-menu .sub-menu").not(EltToToggle).hide();

  EltToToggle.fadeToggle();
});
```

This is my html :

```
<li id="menu-item-1555" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-1555"><a href="#" aria-expanded="false" class="">Nos métiers :  Fonctions support</a>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-1673" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1673"><a href="#">Test insertion shortcode tableau RWD – Alex</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-1600" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1600 menu-item-has-children">
        <a href="#collapseExample3" aria-expanded="false" class="">testu</a>

        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-1656" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1656">
                <a href="#">Test de tableau – page – style 3 Empilement Stacking</a>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Add another class on the second `submenu`. Then You Should select it with the class that you just made for it so the two `submenu` are not identical.:)

Comment: Unfortunately i can't touch the html code, it was generated by a CMS :(

Comment: i made this   `$(".sub-menu .sub-menu").not(EltToToggle).hide();`  but i when i click on another link to open items it does'n close the first one. PLease see my post i edited the Gif

Answer (score 0):

you can just do

javascript

```
$('.btnForExpanding').click(() => {

    $('ul.sub-menu').fadeToggle();

})
```

and HTML

```
<li id="menu-item-1555" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-1555"><a href="#" aria-expanded="false" class="">Nos métiers :  Fonctions support</a>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-1673" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1673"><a href="#">Test insertion shortcode tableau RWD – Alex</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-1600" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1600 menu-item-has-children">
        <a href="#collapseExample3" aria-expanded="false" class="btnForExpanding">testu</a>

        <ul class="sub-menu collapse" id="collapseExample3" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#menu-secondary-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-1656" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1656">
                <a href="#">Test de tableau – page – style 3 Empilement Stacking</a>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: it hide the `<a href="#collapseExample3" aria-expanded="false" class="btnForExpanding">testu</a>` too with a `dispaly:none`

Comment: How can i close others `<ul class="sub-menu">` in the same time please

Comment: any help please ?